# Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'Path'. Specified error

Tags: powershell

I am getting the below error when running powershell script

> **Set-Location : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'Path'. Specified 
>   error      15-May-2018 08:31:42    method is not supported.**

Below is the script which is having issues, Could you please suggest what is wrong here

```
cd $lsolutionPath
    Get-ChildItem -Path "$lsolutionPath" -Filter "*Tests" -Recurse -Directory | where {$_.FullName -inotlike "*.sonarqube*"} | ForEach-Object {
    $fullName = $_.FullName
    $projName = $_.BaseName
    write-output $projName
    write-output $fullName

    Write-Output "Starting Build Helper unit test run:3"
    $tests = Get-ChildItem -Path "$fullName" -Recurse -Include *.dll
    Write-Output "Starting Build Helper unit test run:4"
    if($tests -eq $null) {
        Write-Error "Could not find *Tests.dll"
        return 999
        }

    cd $tests.Directory
    Write-Output $tests.Directory
    Write-Output "target args"
    $targetArgs = "\""$tests\"" -nologo -parallel none -noshadow -xml \""$xUnittestResultsPath\$projName.xml\"" -nunit \""$testResultsPath\$projName.xml\"""
    Write-Output "$target args"
     Write-Output "###### Target Args:"**
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$tests = Get-ChildItem -Path "$fullName" -Recurse -Include *.dll

cd $tests.Directory
```

`cd` is an alias for `Set-Location` and `$tests` contains multiple dll files, and so `$tests.directory` is an array of multiple files, that is what shows up as  `System.Object[]`. You can't change into all of them at the same time.

It is not clear to me which one you want to change into, since you have `-recurse`, so there may be many different directories. Perhaps you need `get-childitem ... | Select-Object -First 1` or perhaps you need a loop over them to process each one.

Comment: I agree +1, the gci for directory is also recursing - so there seems to be a discrepancy what should recurse the `*tests` folder or the `*.dll` files

Answer (score 3):

The `$tests` variable is an array of file objects, and so you may simply need to create another `foreach` loop for the `$tests` array.

Replace this:

```
cd $tests.Directory
Write-Output $tests.Directory
Write-Output "target args"
$targetArgs = "\""$tests\"" -nologo -parallel none -noshadow -xml \""$xUnittestResultsPath\$projName.xml\"" -nunit \""$testResultsPath\$projName.xml\"""
Write-Output "$target args"
 Write-Output "###### Target Args:"**
```

With this:

```
$tests | foreach {
Set-Location $_.Directory
Write-Output $_.Directory
Write-Output "target args"
$targetArgs = "\""$($_.FullName)\"" -nologo -parallel none -noshadow -xml \""$xUnittestResultsPath\$projName.xml\"" -nunit \""$testResultsPath\$projName.xml\"""
Write-Output "$target args"
Write-Output "###### Target Args:"**
}
```